# R highcharter x-axis date issue

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I have a data frame contains month-end data. I'm using the stacked column chart but have an issue with the x-axis date labels. For example, it shows April under the March column.

```
library(highcharter)
df = data.frame(Date = as.Date(c('2020-03-31','2020-03-31','2020-04-30','2020-05-31','2020-05-31','2020-06-30')), Value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), Country = c('US','Mexico','US','Canada','US','Canada'))
hchart(df, "column", hcaes(Date, Value, group = Country)) %>%
   hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal"))
```

I tried to specify the type and labels by adding `hc_xAxis(type = 'datetime', labels = list(format = '{value:%m-%Y}'))`, but it doesn't help. The tooltip shows the correct dates.

[image]

Comment: @Marco Sandri There are only three bars in your output chart because Canada's data (May and June) sits on top of March and April bars. The problem of transforming dates into characters is that it won't display correctly if one of the countries doesn't have a value in any month.

Comment: Hi @MarcoSandri, here is what I got: https://imgur.com/a/I9cMO75. I didn't modify any of your codes at all. I think your codes should work, but I'm not sure why Canada's data is not showing up correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just updated R and all the packages to the latest version, and it worked like a charm! Please add the solution and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and valuable solution is to transform dates into characters.

```
library(highcharter)
 
df = data.frame(Date = as.Date(c('2020-03-31','2020-03-31','2020-04-30',
                                 '2020-05-31','2020-05-31','2020-06-30')), 
                Value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                Country = c('US','Mexico','US','Canada','US','Canada'))
 
df$Date <- as.character(df$Date)
 
hchart(df, "column", hcaes(Date, Value, group = Country)) %>%
   hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
   hc_xAxis(type="category", categories=unique(df$Date))
```

[image]